# Set array based on specific dates

Tags: javascript

Im looking to be able to set an arrays contents based on specific dates i.e.

if the date is the 25/12 then the array would look like the following

```
var compliments = [
            'Happy Xmas!',
            'Hope you been a good boy',

        ];
```

I would like to be able to do this over various dates and also have a default for the non special dates.

I am aware you would need to use the date function in javascript however I'm not experienced enough to work this out.

Comment: Well maybe it is right time to read about date/time functions in JS? `new Date()` to get current date, then check it then assign contents according to your rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index your compliments with a date string.Try something like this.

```
var today = new Date(),
    today_string = today.getMonth() + "-" + today.getDate();
    compliments = {
        "12-25": [
            'Happy Xmas!',
            'Hope you been a good boy'
        ],
        "1-1": ["Happy new year!"],
        "Default": ["Happy today ¬¬"]
    };

console.log(compliments[today_string] || compliments["default"]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use objects line array.

```
var compliments = {}
compliments['12/05'] = ['bla1', 'bla2'];
compliments['13/06'] = ['bla3', 'bla4'];
```

you can access them like this:

```
alert(compliments['12/05'][0] + compliments['12/05'][1]);
```